# How to display only the negative values, and make all the positive values display as 0?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have written a query to display this data, the last column gives data by using this query.

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,booking_activity.activity_time,booking.pick_up_time) AS ActualWaitingTime
```

Now, I have to only display the negative values, and all the positive values should become 0.

How should this query be edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
CASE
     WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,booking_activity.activity_time,booking.pick_up_time) < 0 
          THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,booking_activity.activity_time,booking.pick_up_time)
     ELSE 0
END AS ActualWaitingTime
```

Comment: But I don't want to display the '-' sign, is there a way to do that?

Comment: You could wrap it like this `THEN REPLACE(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,booking_activity.activity_time,booking.pick_up_time),'-','')`

Comment: While @KayNelson's approach works, it return a string, using ABS() is better.

Comment: ...or multiply by -1 or reverse the two date arguments. Also there's `greatest(0, ...)`...

Answer (score 0):

you can use the CASE function to make anything greater than or equal to zero as zero

or alternatively in your WHEN clause to only return values less than zero